# Apt-fast does not show download size

Tags: installation, apt, apt-fast

I use apt-fast to download and install packages on my system. What I have noticed is apt-fast does not show me how much data will be downloaded, as apt-get does:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
dkms libgsoap2 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 19.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 77.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

How can I avail this feature when installing from apt-fast?

Answer (score 1):

This is by-design. You should open a feature request over [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt-fast/+filebug) or upstream in [GitHub](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast/issues/new).